# Xunit: Getting Error in Amazone S3 Services Unit Test

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing, amazon-s3, xunit

I am trying to write a unit test of the method bellow :

```
 public class AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager : IMediaManager
{
    private readonly IImageCache imageCache;
    private readonly IAmazonS3 storageClient;
    private readonly string bucket;
    public AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager(string region, string
        accessKey, string secretAccessKey, string bucket, IImageCache
        imageCache)
    {
        storageClient = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey,
            RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));
        this.bucket = bucket;
        this.imageCache = imageCache;
    }
    public async Task DeleteImageAsync(string category, string parentId,
        string name)
    {

        try
        {
            var request = new DeleteObjectRequest
            {
                Key = $"{category}/{parentId}/{name}",
                BucketName = bucket,
            };

            await storageClient.DeleteObjectAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to delete file '{name}' to AWS S3 bucket '{bucket}'.", except);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error: "No such host is known. (your-bucket.s3.your-region.amazonaws.com:443)'
" It seems its trying to establish a socket connection.But in the following code i mocked it .But somehow the mocking is not returning as expected hence it throws error.

```
public class AwsSimpleStorageMediaManagerTest
{
    protected AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager;
    protected Mock<IAmazonS3> mockStorageClient;

    public AwsSimpleStorageMediaManagerTest()
    {
        AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager = new AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager(
            "your-region",
            "your-access-key",
            "your-secret-access-key",
            "your-bucket",
            CreateMockImageCache());
        mockStorageClient = new Mock<IAmazonS3>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task DeleteImageAsync_SuccessfullyDeletesImage()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedKey = "category/parentId/name";
        mockStorageClient
            .Setup(x => x.DeleteObjectAsync(It.IsAny<DeleteObjectRequest>(),It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new DeleteObjectResponse());

        // Act
        await AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager.DeleteImageAsync("category", "parentId", "name");

        // Assert
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that the mock `storageClient` is not passed as a dependency when mocking the `AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager`.

As a result `IAmazonS3 storageClient`
for your `AwsSimpleStorageMediaManager` class is not calling mocked implementation.